# glsl double-precision vertex buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

If I create a double-precision vertex buffer, for example:

```
GLuint vertBuffer, spanBuffer, spanCount, patchSize, program; // already setup
glUseProgram (program);
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, 0);
glPatchParameteri (GL_PATCH_VERTICES, patchSize);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, spanBuffer);
glDrawElements (GL_PATCHES,  spanCount * patchSize, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

How do I access the double precision data in my vertex shader? Should I be able to do this?

```
// GLSL VERTEX SHADER
#version 410

in dvec4 gl_Vertex;

void main ()
{
<snip>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. At least, not that way.

If you want to use OpenGL 4.x+'s ability to read double-precision values into your shader, then you *must* use generic vertex attributes. You can't use old fixed-function `gl_Vertex` and `glVertexPointer` anymore. You must use [`glVertexAttribLPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttribPointer), with a proper generic vertex attribute index.