# Does this look like a vertex attribute/layout issue?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex

I have a project that's been working fine using floats, and I've changed it to use doubles instead of floats, and it doesn't work anymore.  I've got a feeling it's maybe the layout of my Vertex, and now the Vertex has 3 position doubles, 3 normal doubles, and 2 texCoord floats. Does the following image look like this is a vertex layout/stride/size issue? Looks strange to me.

[image]

Here is my Vertex struct:

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::dvec3 position;   // 24 bytes 
    glm::dvec3 normal;     // 24 bytes
    glm::vec2 texCoords;   // 8 bytes
};  On the CPU there is no padding. Shader side there would be for a block, but for attributes I don't think it matters.
```

My vertex shader looks like this:

```
layout (location = 0) in dvec3 position;         
layout (location = 2) in dvec3 vertNormal;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 vertTexCoords;
layout (location = 0) out dvec3 fragWorldPos;
layout (location = 2) out dvec3 fragNormal;
layout (location = 4) out vec2 fragTexCoords;
```

My fragment shader:

```
layout (location = 0) flat in dvec3 fragWorldPos;
layout (location = 2) flat in dvec3 fragNormal;
layout (location = 4) in vec2 fragTexCoords;
layout (location = 5) out vec4 outFragColour;
```

And my vertex attributes:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, 56, (void*)nullptr);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1 (should be 2?), 3, GL_DOUBLE, GL_FALSE, 56, (void*)(3 * sizeof(double)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); //Should be ?

    glVertexAttribPointer(2 (should be 4?), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 56, (void*)(48));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); //Should be ?
```

It basically looks like what happens when you're graphics card is about to die. It flickers a lot.

Comment: Offtopic - what is this fancy debug GUI?

Comment: @Starl1ght It's called ImGUI, it's one of the more popular immediate mode GUIs, fairly minimal, simple, and good for what it is, but I'm not a fan of the whole immediate mode thing. Can you recommend any good ones? I haven't tried AntTweak bar. Eventually I'll want something prettier and with more features for a game.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: you are not sending any 64bit floats to the shader, you are telling the GL to convert it to float first, and accessing that as a `dvec` is just undefined behavior. See for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823811/glsl-double-precision-vertex-buffer) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014864/why-different-variations-of-glvertexattribpointer-do-exist) for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. `location` in vertex shader must match `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`. So, vertex shader must be edited.
2. afaik, you should not specify location for `out` argument in vertex shader and for any arguments in fragment shader, they should be just passed as-is by name.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I'm using location explicitly is because I'm using separate programs bound to a pipeline object. I think it's a more new feature that let's you mix and match different shader programs, and the matching rules are a bit different.  So the location must match the vertexAttrib functions? Because in the docs they call it the index. That's good to know. I changed it but it didn't fix the problem. I didn't change it in the shader because in the shader they need to be 0, 2 and 4, as dvec takes two locations.  This is really hard.

Comment: yep, match it in vertexAttrib function then.

Comment: Have you used Vulkan? I know Vulkan is harder than OpenGL, but just between you and me, I'm not particularly fond of OpenGL.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice never used it, but afaik, Vulkan is far more complex, since it exposes a lot of low-level stuff, hidden in OpenGL

Comment: @Starl1ght: "*you should not specify location for out argument in vertex shader and for any arguments in fragment shader, they should be just passed as-is by name.*" Nonsense. [Interfaces can match by location too](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Interface_matching), given an appropriate OpenGL version. Not to mention, FS output locations [have to be mapped to color attachments](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers), so specifying them is rather important.